# How to know which app on device has invoked a particular GMS service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-wake-lock

I work with an Android vendor. One of issues we are looking at, involves,

one of the GMS services holding "net_scheduler" wakelock for a good duration preventing device from entering sleep, is there some way to find on behalf of which app gms is holding wakelock?

Comment: If you are actually working for an Android vendor, who legitimately has rights to install GMS on your device, presumably you have access to technical contacts within Google who can answer your questions regarding GMS behavior. Conversely, since GMS is closed-source, it is highly unlikely that anyone else is going to be able to help you.

Comment: I get your point, but the thing is, I think there might not be any issue with gms, otherwise it would reproduce much more often than it is doing right now, So, gms services will acquire wakelock, most probably on behalf of a 3rd party app which requests it to, I was thinking of a way to find out, which app has requested that, maybe only way is to get assistance from folks who have written gms code at google!